# Maximal ideal of a point is principal

Tags: algebraic-geometry, maximal-and-prime-ideals, affine-varieties

Let $X$ be an affine variety  defined by a smooth curve $F=0$ on $\mathbb{A}^2$. Let $p=(a,b)$ be a point on $X$. Now $m_p$ be the maximal ideal generated by $x-a,y-b$. Then why $$F_X(p)(x-a)+F_Y(p)(y-b)\equiv 0\bmod{m_p^2}$$
Where $F_X$ is the partial derivative of $F$ with respect to $X$.

Now using this equation we obtain that $m_p/m_p^2$ has dimension 1 as a vector space of the residue field $k\cong \mathcal{O}_p/m_p$. Hence using nakayama's lemma we can conclude that $m_p$ is generated by one element.

But how $F_X(p)(x-a)+F_Y(p)(y-b)\equiv 0\bmod{m_p^2}$ is true.

Comment: Hint: write out $F=F_0+F_1+F_2+\cdots$ for $F_i$ homogeneous of degree $i$ in $(x-a)$ and $(y-b)$. What happens when you analyze this term-by-term?

Comment: $F\in m_p$ so $F_0=0$. Now all $F_i$ for $i\geq 2$ are in $m_p^2$. That leaves only  $F_1$. Now $F_1$ is the equation $F_X(p)(x-a)+F_Y(p)(y-b)$. But why this will also be in $m_p^2$

Comment: You're working in a ring where $F=0$, right? Think about the expression $F=F_0+F_1+F_2+\cdots$ again.